# Best way to automatically add stomp native headers to headers

Tags: spring-integration, spring-websocket

Our javascript websocket clients adds "custom" headers to all `STOMP` messages.
My project handles websocket endpoints using spring-websocket `@Controller`.

```
@MessageMapping(value = "/mymessages")
public void save(@Payload ToBeSaved payload, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
    service.save(toMsg(payload, headers));
}  

protected <P> Message<P> toMsg(P payload, MessageHeaders headers) {
    return MessageBuilder.createMessage(payload, headers);
}
```

The controller modifies the payload and then passes the new payload and original websocket headers (including the custom ones) to a spring-integration `@MessagingGateway`.

The underlying `IntegrationFlow` tries to access the "custom" headers by accessing the message headers with the SPLExpression `headers['custom']`.
Unfortunately `headers['custom']` is always null because `custom` is actually contained in the `nativeHeaders`.

I haven't found a way to tell `IntegrationFlow` to look into `nativeHeaders`.

Is there a way in spring-websocket to copy all native headers as normal headers ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spring-websocket can do nothing for your on the matter. It isn't its responsibility.

If you would really like to have access to something in the `nativeHeaders`, you should do that manually.

For your particular case that SpEL may look like:

```
headers['nativeHeaders']['custom']
```

Because `nativeHeaders` is a `Map` as well.

From other side you can use `<header-enricher>` in your down stream flow to pop all those `nativeHeaders` to top level.

And one more point: since Spring Integration `4.2` we provide native support for STOMP adapters. And there is a `StompHeaderMapper` which does exactly what you want and the code there looks like:

```
 else if (StompHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS.equals(name)) {
            MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap =
                    headers.get(StompHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS, MultiValueMap.class);
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry1 : multiValueMap.entrySet()) {
                name = entry1.getKey();
                if (shouldMapHeader(name, this.outboundHeaderNames)) {
                    String value = entry1.getValue().get(0);
                    if (StringUtils.hasText(value)) {
                        setStompHeader(target, name, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried `headers['nativeHeaders']['custom']` yet but will in the future.